# writing to excel sheet in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I was trying to write to excel sheet by using panda which I successfully did. 
I have to questions:
**First**  I have tried to sort by column but I couldn't. I used *df.sort_index, df.sortlevel*
both did not get what I want.
this my code:

```
df = DataFrame({'Seq Label':['if >= 1','if >= 2','if >= 3','if >= 4','if >= 5','if >= 6','if >= 7'],
            'TP':[countTP, twocountTP, threecountTP, fourcountTP, fivecountTP, sixcountTP, sevencountTP], 
            'TN':[countTN, twocountTN, threecountTN, fourcountTN, fivecountTN, sixcountTN, sevencountTN], 
            'FP':[countFP, twocountFP, threecountFP, fourcountFP, fivecountFP, sixcountFP, sevencountFP], 
            'FN':[countFN, twocountFN, threecountFN, fourcountFN, fivecountFN, sixcountFN, sevencountFN]})
df.to_excel('Book10.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

It gives me this output which I don't want:

```
    FN   FP Seq Label     TN    TP
0  123  125   if >= 1  20296  7671
1  123  125   if >= 2  17142  6274
2  123  125   if >= 3   3810  1307
3    7   11   if >= 4    419   213
4    1    4   if >= 5    127    74
5    0    0   if >= 6      0     0
6    0    0   if >= 7      0     0
```

I want it sort table as the order I have in my df in the code. I want it
sort it as:

```
Seq Label   TP   TN    FP    FN
```

**Second Question**
How to write on an existing excel sheet without deleting or writing on other data. 
I have tried to use different libs. such as

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import xlrd
```

I am sorry if I make it too long. I need your help
Thanks

Comment: Only one question per post please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about rearranging columns within data frame `df` as needed, and then write to excel. That way you don't have to worry about excel end.
**NOTE:**  Values in columns are fictitious.

```
>>> df = df[['Seq Label', 'TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']]
>>> df
  Seq Label  TP  TN  FP  FN
0   if >= 1   1   1   1   1
1   if >= 2   2   2   2   2
2   if >= 3   3   3   3   3
3   if >= 4   4   4   4   4
4   if >= 5   5   5   5   5
5   if >= 6   6   6   6   6
6   if >= 7   7   7   7   7
>>> df.to_excel('Book10.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: if my answer solved your problem do accept the answer by clicking up arrow next to answer so that community is aware that issue is resolved. See here for howto https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Do you have an idea about the second question? I appreciate your help

Comment: I did click on the up arrow but won't allow me because my reputation is under 15. Thank you though

Comment: Yes, you will need to get last row of existing worksheet and specify next row for writing your data. It becomes a bit complicated. Its advisable to ask one question at a time, else it creates confusion. If you ask another question let me know, I can answer in details. OR search for this keyword "pandas python to_excel append"

Answer (score 1):

First sort the dataframe, then write it to Excel.

```
df.sort_values(['Seq Label', 'TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']).to_excel(...)
```

*EDIT*

Oh, you just want to rearrange your columns into a desired order.  Try:

```
df[['Seq Label', 'TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']].to_excel(...)
```

The order of the items in a dictionary is not guaranteed.  If you use a dictionary to construct your dataframe and have a target ordering in mind, you can do something like:

```
desired_order = [['Seq Label', 'TP', 'TN', 'FP', 'FN']]
df_order = [k for k in df if k in desired_order] + [k for k in df if k not in desired_order]
df = df[df_order]
```

This will sort the dataframe in your desired order if the keys are present in the dataframe.  Any column not in the desired order would then be appended to the right hand side of columns.

Comment: it didn't work with me. As you can see in my dataframe I used ~{ }~ dict. I couldn't get it the way I ordered it.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work".  What was the error?

Comment: it gives the same first table I post it which I don't want. I need the same order I put in the dataframe. I need first Col to be '' Seq Label", Sec Col "TP",... etc

Answer (score 1):

```
from xlutils.copy import copy  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils
from xlrd import open_workbook # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
from xlwt import easyxf # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

rb = open_workbook('file.xlrd',formatting_info=True)
r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) # read only copy to introspect the file
wb = copy(rb) # a writable copy (I can't read values out of this, only write to it)
w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) # the sheet to write to within the writable copy
w_sheet.write(row, col, 'Value') 
wb.save(file_path)
```

> here you can give row and column number or use for loop for writing continuous data cell. I used this. it's work perfect for me.